# Logging into facebook bug

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, ios6

I have implemented the new FacebookSDK 3.0 beta into my project and I have the loginview working however sometimes when I click the login button and it says "You have already authorized this account for this app" and hit the okay button, it goes to another login screen where it asks me to type in my facebook username/password and when I hit log in, it does not go away.  About 50% of the time this happens.  Also in the console it says something like this:

```
scheduled GC timer for 9125.000000
 seconds
scheduled GC timer for 2.227783
 seconds
scheduled GC timer for 1.041191
 seconds
scheduled GC timer for 43625.000000
 seconds
scheduled GC timer for 28.036632
 seconds
scheduled GC timer for 9.426318
 seconds
scheduled GC timer for 4.049851
 seconds
scheduled GC timer for 1.891804
 seconds
scheduled GC timer for 0.917706
 seconds
scheduled GC timer for 191475.000000
 seconds
scheduled GC timer for 124.658203
 seconds
scheduled GC timer for 62.329102
 seconds
scheduled GC timer for 31.164551
 seconds
scheduled GC timer for 15.264270
 seconds
```

and this goes on as long as I keep hitting log in.

Is this a bug on facebooks part? or am I doing something wrong

Also, I am using xcode 4.5, and this is on the ios 6.0 iphone simulator.

Comment: Could you post your login code?

Comment: i have exacly this same problem. it look like iOS6 webview or facebook delegate didn't react

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the "scheduled GC timer" is something to do with the iOS 6 beta SDK that you are using. I get the same thing doing something totally non-Facebook related (I am making an HTTP post using `NSURLConnection`)

I do not think it will be Facebook's issue - more likely just bugs / debug in the beta SDK.

Comment: I switched some for loops to dispatch_apply() and the "scheduled GC timer" message started appearing when I run the app on my iPad. I have hunch that "GC" has something to do with "Grand Central Dispatch" and that the FacebookSDK and NSURLConnection use GCD.